# Phonegap 3.0 Media undefined

Tags: android, html, cordova

I try to add some audio features to my android / phonegap html5 app, but i have an error from my code `var snd = new Media(media_path);`  saying that Media is undefined.

Referring to http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media , 
i added `<feature name="Media">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler" />
</feature>` into app/res/xml/config.xml, 
and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
 into app/AndroidManifest.xml, but it didn't change anything.

Did i miss something ?

Comment: Have you added capture plugin?

Comment: No, is it needed !?
I just want to play sounds, not to capture any ...

Comment: yes,  read the text below **Accessing the Feature** in your link

Comment: Well, i read it's needed for BlackBerry WebWorks, not for Android, correct !?

Comment: yes, its needed for both android as well blackberry! read again :)